# thread execution error for the second time android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent

good afternoon, excuse my English is not very good; I have an application with various activities but basically could be defined as follows:

Main activity> New Alarm> Main activities> Alarm> New Alarm> thread execution error

Basically the main activity, I have an ExpandableListView with a personal adapter, which coordinates the options menu; to just click on the menu alarm and then the menu sub new alarm, redirects to the activity New alarm, volume information the entry into a database and run a service (Hilo) that is responsible for comparing the system time with the introduced.

Code MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    SparseArray<GrupoDeItems> grupos = new SparseArray<GrupoDeItems>();
    Hilos hilo,hilo2;
    Switch estado_drunk_blocker;
    Switch estado_alarma;
    GrupoDeItems grupo0 = new GrupoDeItems("Drunk Blocker");
    GrupoDeItems grupo1 = new GrupoDeItems("Alarma");
    adaptador adapter;
    Intent salto = new Intent();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        crearDatos();
        hilo2 = new Hilos("bd");
        hilo2.execute();


        estado_drunk_blocker = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        estado_alarma = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch2);
        ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewexp);
        adaptador adapter = new adaptador(this, grupos);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void crearDatos() {
        grupo0.children.add("Preferencias");
        grupo0.children.add("Configuración");
        grupos.append(0, grupo0);

        grupo1.children.add(0,"Nueva Alarma");
        grupos.append(1, grupo1);
    }

    public void AgregarAlarma_ConPos(String valor,int posicion){
        grupo1.children.add(posicion,valor);
        grupos.append(1,grupo1);
    }

    public void AgregarAlarma(String valor){
        grupo1.children.add(valor);
        grupos.append(1,grupo1);
    }

    public void LanzarDrunkBlocker(View view) throws InterruptedException {
        boolean on = estado_drunk_blocker.isChecked();
        if (on) {
            hilo = new Hilos("drunk blocker");
            hilo.execute();
        }
    }

    public void GenerarSaltos(Activity origen, Class destino){
        salto.setClass(origen,destino);
        startActivity(salto);
    }

   /* public void GenerarSaltos_ConservandoValores(Activity origen, Class destino, int codigo){

        Intent salto = new Intent(origen,destino);
        origen.startActivityForResult(salto,codigo);
    }
 */

    public void HacerUnaPausa(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public class Hilos extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        String valor;
        Cursor cursor;
        DataBaseManager manager;

       public Hilos(String parametro){
           valor = parametro;
       }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        boolean pasar = true;

            if(valor.equals("drunk blocker")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                    HacerUnaPausa();
                    if (!estado_drunk_blocker.isChecked()) {
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Entre en la cancelacion",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        cancel(true);
                        pasar = false;
                        break;
                    }

                }

                if (pasar) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Drunk_Blocker.class));
                    cancel(true);
                }
            }


            if (valor.equals("bd")){
                Actualizar_Alarmas();
                Verificar_Hilo_Alarma();
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            if(valor.equals("drunk blocker")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Cuenta con 10 segundos antes del bloqueo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }

        public void Actualizar_Alarmas(){
            manager = new DataBaseManager(MainActivity.this);
            cursor = manager.Cargar_Cursor_Alarmas();

            int posicion = 1;
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    String id = cursor.getString(0);
                    String horas = cursor.getString(1);
                    String minutos = cursor.getString(2);
                    String horario = cursor.getString(3);
                    String etiqueta = cursor.getString(4);
                    String estado_alarma = cursor.getString(5);

                    AgregarAlarma_ConPos(horas + ":" + minutos + " " + horario + "       " + etiqueta + " ---" + estado_alarma, posicion);
                    posicion++;
                }while(cursor.moveToNext());

                cursor.close();

            }
        }

        public void Verificar_Hilo_Alarma(){
            manager = new DataBaseManager(MainActivity.this);
            cursor = manager.Cargar_Cursor_Alarmas();

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    String id = cursor.getString(0);
                    String horas = cursor.getString(1);
                    String minutos = cursor.getString(2);
                    String horario = cursor.getString(3);
                    String etiqueta = cursor.getString(4);
                    String estado_alarma = cursor.getString(5);
                    if (estado_alarma.equals("activa")){
                       // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Si hay una alarma activa!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      //  manager.Insertar_Tabla_Estado_Hilo(0);
                       // int probando=Buscar_Datos_Hilo(manager);
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"probando : "+probando+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        //if (probando==1){
                   //       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Si veo TABLAAAAAAAA!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //  cursor.moveToLast();
                          //manager.Modificar_Campo_Tabla_Hilo("1",1);
                          startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class));
                          cancel(true);
                          onCancelled();
                          break;

                       //}
                    }
                    }while(cursor.moveToNext());

                cursor.close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The first time it runs successfully to arrive and be both equal times are redirected to the alarm activity which does what it should and redirects to the main activity, the problem arises when attempting to create or modify a new arlama to enter data and press the Pin accept a thread execution error is generated, said the thread is already running and can not run again.

I end each wire fulfilled the condition that interests me, not that is running a second time or if the activities have redirected no stopped successfully and some puntoo rerun the service, maybe could be the main activity is not completed in the adapter even though you control the activity and work as parameters the adapter and

```
public adapter (Activity act ....) {
```

activity = act;
    }

Code adapter (personal adapter)

```
public class adaptador extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private final SparseArray<GrupoDeItems> grupos;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;
    public Activity activity;
    MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();

    // Constructor
    public adaptador(Activity act, SparseArray<GrupoDeItems> grupos) {
        activity = act;
        this.grupos = grupos;
        inflater = act.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    // Nos devuelve los datos asociados a un subitem en base
    // a la posición

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return grupos.get(groupPosition).children.get(childPosition);
    }

    // Devuelve el id de un item o subitem en base a la
    // posición de item y subitem

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    // En base a la posición del item y de subitem nos devuelve
    // el objeto view correspondiente y el layout para los subitems

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String children = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        TextView textvw = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subitems_layout, null);
        }
        textvw = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textvw.setText(children);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent ine = new Intent();
                //Esto emite una pequeña ventana de alerta con el mensaje seleccionado
                //Toast.makeText(activity, children, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                switch (groupPosition){
                    case 0:
                        ine.setClass(activity,Drunk_Blocker.class);
                        switch (childPosition){
                          case 0:
                                activity.startActivity(ine);
                                //obj.GenerarSaltos(activity,Drunk_Blocker.class);
                                break;

                          case 1:
                                activity.startActivity(ine);
                                //obj.GenerarSaltos(activity,Drunk_Blocker.class);
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:

                        DataBaseManager manager = new DataBaseManager(activity);
                        Cursor cursor = manager.Cargar_Cursor_Alarmas();
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        switch (childPosition){
                            case 0:
                                ine.setClass(activity,Nueva_Alarma.class);
                                if(cursor.getCount()<3) {
                                    activity.finish();
                                    activity.startActivity(ine);
                                }
                                else
                                   Toast.makeText(activity,"Solo puede tener 1 alarma",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                //obj.GenerarSaltos(activity,Alarma.class);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                activity.finish();
                                ine.setClass(activity,Modificar_Alarma.class);
                                ine.putExtra("identificador",cursor.getString(0));
                                activity.startActivity(ine);
                                break;

                            case 2:
                                cursor.moveToPosition(1);
                                ine.setClass(activity,Modificar_Alarma.class);
                                ine.putExtra("identificador",cursor.getString(0));
                                activity.startActivity(ine);
                                break;

                            case 3:
                          /*      cursor.moveToPosition(2);
                                ine.setClass(activity,Modificar_Alarma.class);
                                ine.putExtra("identificador",cursor.getString(0));
                                activity.startActivity(ine);
                                break;

                            case 4:
                                cursor.moveToPosition(3);
                                ine.setClass(activity,Modificar_Alarma.class);
                                ine.putExtra("identificador",cursor.getString(0));
                                activity.startActivity(ine);
                                break;

                            case 5:
                                cursor.moveToPosition(4);
                                ine.setClass(activity,Modificar_Alarma.class);
                                ine.putExtra("identificador",cursor.getString(0));
                                activity.startActivity(ine);
                                break;*/
                            //asigna una imagen a un teim o subitem
                            //textvw.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.pescadofrito, 0, 0, 0);

                        }
                        cursor.close();
                       // 
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        textvw.setText(children);

        return convertView;
    }

    // Nos devuelve la cantidad de subitems que tiene un ítem
    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return grupos.get(groupPosition).children.size();
    }


    //Los datos de un ítem especificado por groupPosition
    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return grupos.get(groupPosition);
    }

    //La cantidad de ítem que tenemos definidos
    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return grupos.size();
    }

    //Método que se invoca al contraer un ítem
    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    //Método que se invoca al expandir un ítem
    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    //Devuelve el id de un ítem
    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    //Obtenemos el layout para los ítems
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items_layout, null);
        }
        GrupoDeItems grupo = (GrupoDeItems) getGroup(groupPosition);
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(grupo.string);
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    //Nos informa si es seleccionable o no un ítem o subitem
    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Code Myservice(Thread Alarm)

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    Intent salto = new Intent();
    MyTask myTask;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarma creada!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        myTask = new MyTask();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //Toast.makeText(this,"Antes de ejecutar------------------ "+myTask.getStatus().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (myTask.getStatus().toString().equals("FINISHED") || myTask.getStatus().toString().equals("PENDING")) {

            if (myTask.getStatus().toString().equals("RUNNING")){
                myTask.cancel(true);
            }

            myTask.execute();
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
      //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarma cancelada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        myTask.cancel(true);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    public void GenerarSaltos(Activity origen, Class destino){
        salto.setClass(origen,destino);
        startActivity(salto);
    }

public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private DateFormat dateFormat;
    private String date;
    private boolean cent;
    DataBaseManager manager;
    Cursor cursor;
    ArrayList<String> vec2 = new ArrayList<String>();
  /*  public MyTask(Activity act){
        manager = new DataBaseManager(act);
        activity2 = act;
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        cent = true;
        manager = new DataBaseManager(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String cadena;
        String[] vec;
        int horas_sys=0,minutos_sys=0,segundos_sys=0;
        while (cent){
            date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
            cursor = manager.Cargar_Cursor_Alarmas();
            cadena = date;
            vec = cadena.split(":");
            horas_sys =  Integer.parseInt(vec[0]);
            minutos_sys =  Integer.parseInt(vec[1]);
            segundos_sys =  Integer.parseInt(vec[2]);
            if (horas_sys>12){
                horas_sys = horas_sys - 12;
            }else{
                if (horas_sys==0){
                    horas_sys=12;
                }
            }

           // publishProgress(horas_sys+" "+minutos_sys+" "+segundos_sys);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    String id = cursor.getString(0);
                    String horas = cursor.getString(1);
                    String minutos = cursor.getString(2);
                    String horario = cursor.getString(3);
                    String etiqueta = cursor.getString(4);
                    String estado_alarma = cursor.getString(5);
                  //  publishProgress("horas sistema: "+horas_sys+" hora alarma: "+horas);
                    if (horas_sys==Integer.parseInt(horas)){
                       // publishProgress("Solo horas: "+horas);

                        if (minutos_sys==Integer.parseInt(minutos)){
                          //publishProgress("Horas: " + horas + " minutos " + minutos);
                            cursor = manager.Cargar_Cursor_Alarmas();
                            vec2 = manager.Recorrer_Cursor(cursor);
                            cadena = Recorrer_ArrayList(vec2);
                            manager.Modificar_Campo("1",cadena);


                            Intent hola = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Alarma.class);
                                hola.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(hola);

                                cent = false;
                                cancel(true);
                                onCancelled();
                                break;

                            }
                        }
                     }while(cursor.moveToNext());
                    cursor.close();
                }

                if (cent==true){
                    try {
                        // Stop 5s
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


            }
            return null;
        }

        public String Recorrer_ArrayList(ArrayList<String> vec){
            String[] cadena = vec.get(0).split("/");
            String retorno = cadena[0];

            for (int i = 1; i <cadena.length -1 ; i++) {
                retorno = retorno + "/" + cadena[i];
            }

            retorno = retorno + "/" + "noactiva";
            return retorno;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), values[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
            cent = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: `AsyncTask` can only be used once. If you want to run it again you need to create a new one.

Comment: to stop a AsyncTask, and finish I can not run the same AsyncTask again?

Comment: in `onCreate()` you create the `AsyncTask`. In `onStartCommand()` you use the `AsyncTask`. If `onStartCommand()` is called again, it attempts to use the `AsyncTask` again. This is not permitted.

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` can only be used once. In onCreate() you create the `AsyncTask`. In `onStartCommand()` you use the AsyncTask. If `onStartCommand()` is called again, it attempts to use the `AsyncTask` again. This is not permitted.

Create your `AsyncTask` in `onStartCommand()`.

Answer (score 0):

finally solved the problem by invoking the method stopActivity () in MyService class when my condition is fulfilled for it to stop, finished both the thread as service and works properly.